# deserialize xml where string may contain xml/html

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize XML where an element may contain html. Something like this here:

```
<member name="P:System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.CdnPath">
    <summary>Gets or sets an alternate url for the bundle when it is stored in a content delivery network.</summary>
    <returns>An alternate url for the bundle <b>when it is stored</b> in a content delivery network.</returns>
</member>
```

I'm reading and writing it with:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlResult));

using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(@"myxml.xml"))
    element = (XmlResult)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"myxml-Copy.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, element);
```

wished behaviour after deserializing is, that it's equal to the original file:

```
<returns>An alternate url for the bundle <b>when it is stored</b> in a content delivery network.</returns>
```

actual behaviour after deserializing is

```
<returns>An alternate url for the bundle  in a content delivery network.</returns>
```

the whole text in `<b>...</b>` is gone. (Since it's not a separate object, I know)
Any idea how I could solve it, that undefined xml-elements stay in the string? or, at least, that I get the whole text? The `<b>` is not important for me.

Comment: Read file as string and replace : <b>  with : &lt;b&gt; and replace : </b> with : &lt;/b&gt;

Comment: So I would have to replace ALL html-tags. sounds like poor performance. (The XML is C#-Class-Documentation, here could be any HTML inside). But yeah, would be a solution, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("member")]
public class Member
{
    [XmlElement("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Returns { get; set; }
}
```

Subscribe `XmlSerializer` to `UnknownElement` event.

In the event handler manually set our property to the data.

```
private static void Serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (Member)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    element.Returns = e.Element.InnerXml;
}
```

Please note that the property name should not match the xml node name (case sensitive). Only in this case the event is triggered. If the names match, use the `XmlIgnore` attribute.

Then we can deserialize the data as follows:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Member));
serializer.UnknownElement += Serializer_UnknownElement;

Member element;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"test.txt"))
    element = (Member)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

However, serialization in this case will differ from the original data.

Comment: This definitely looks like the right solution. Nice one. Works!

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this worked very good. I'm wondering how to apply it for an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The XmlTextReader is trying to parse the HTML as if it is XML. But XML does not allow you to have nested tags inside the content of another tag:

```
<parent_tag> tag text part 1 <nested_tag> illegal inside the content of parent_tag </nested_tag> tag text part 2 </parent_tag>
```

This is legal, but not much help to you

```
<parent_tag>
    <part_1> tag text part 1 </part_1>
    <nested_tag> now ok as in the hierarchy of parent_tag </nested_tag>
    <part_2> tag text part 2 </part_2>
</parent_tag>
```

@jdweng's suggestion of replacing `<b>` with `&lt;b&gt;` and `</b>` with `&lt;/b&gt;` is the easiest. You'd also have to handle all the other embedded tags like `<a>`, `<i>`, `<strong>`, `<em>` etc.

You could also try this which will handle just about any HTML. Note that you can't have the CEND sequence anywhere within the HTML i.e. `]]>`.

```
<member name="P:System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.CdnPath">
<![CDATA[
    <summary>Gets or sets an alternate url for the bundle when it is stored in a content delivery network.</summary>
    <returns>An alternate url for the bundle <b>when it is stored</b> in a content delivery network.</returns>
]]> 
</member>
```

The CDATA section tells XML parser to treat the contents as literal text.
You could preprocess the XML file (as plain text) to insert the CDATA and CEND tags around any text inside all the `<member> ... </member>` tags.

Comment: Would be nice, but this sounds a bit like string replacing, moving,splitting, concattinating,... But I'm working with C#-library-documentations (xml), they can be really big. I don't think preprocessing is the right solution here. But I guess, for a small project this would be great (here have my +1)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. I figured I could use an XmlDocument object and take advantage of the SelectSingleNode or SelectNodes methods with a little XPath magic. I was able to extract what I needed.

```
string input= "a really long string with an xml which contains html to be converted to pdfs.";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(input)
XmlNodeList docsHtmlList = xdoc.SelecetNodes("pdf-gen/content/doc/.");
```

after that it was just a matter of getting the InnerText from each XmlNode.

**UPDATE** Instead of using LoadXml, switch to:

```
string input= "a really long string with an xml which contains html to be converted to pdfs.";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
using (var xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(input)))
{
   xmlreader.XmlResolver = null;
   xmlreader.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
   xdoc.Load(xmlreader);
}
XmlNodeList docsHtmlList = xdoc.SelecetNodes("pdf-gen/content/doc/.");
```